# Can I configure redis persistence so that snapshot RDB file and AOF file are saved in remote machine?

Tags: redis

Can I configure redis persistence so that snapshot RDB file and AOF file are saved in remote machine? If so, I am thinking to put them to the cloud storage. This setup is simple and relatively robust as I do not need to use complex solutions like redis sentinel or cluster to achieve robustness.

The closest alternative is I write a separate cronjob to copy RDB and AOF file to cloud storage. But if I can make redis to directly save them to cloud, that will save the extra cron job.

Please let me know what you think.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis supports persisting RDB / AOF only on the local filesystem.

To persist your data on a cloud storage you could either use a cronjob to upload the local files to the remote storage, as you mentioned, or mount ([AWS](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse), [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux?tabs=smb311), [GCP](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/)) the target cloud storage bucket to a local filesystem directory and just configure Redis to persist data there.